# How to find $\int_{2}^{\infty } \frac{{\rm d} x}{x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, improper-integrals

I'm reviewing a probability question.

$$\Bbb P(X>2) = \int_{2}^{\infty } \frac{{\rm d} x}{x^2} = \left( -\frac1x \right)\Bigg|_2^{\infty } = \frac12$$

I do know how we obtain the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x^2}$, which is $-\frac1x$, but I also don't understand the notation $-1/x |2_{\infty}$ and how $\frac12$ is derived. Thank you.

Comment: The result f your integral has an $x$ in it, so you can substitute values for it.  Correct your integral and try again.

Comment: Um ... it looks like you never describe _what the problem you're trying to solve is_ but leap directly to asking about small bits of an unseen solution to an unseen problem. It will likely be impossible to help you unless you reveal _a lot_ more about what on earth is going on here. To begin with, what is the _question_ that $2/x^2$ is supposed to be an answer to?

Comment: Hi @Troposphere I edited the question a bit sorry for not being initially clear

Comment: Remember that to compute an integral of a function $f$ over $[a,b]$, we find an antiderivative $F$ and evaluate $F(b)-F(a)$ (this is the FTC). So the notation you were confused about just means to compute the difference of $-1/x$ evaluated at $\infty$ (really the limit at $\infty$) and $-1/x$ evaluated at $2$.

Comment: @csch2: Why not turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on the comment of @csch2,

When we trying to calculate the antiderivative of a value that one of its bounds to $\infty$,

$$\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_2^\infty$$

We substitute a variable and take its `limit` to $\infty$ as $\infty$ is not clear value.

$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\left[-\frac{1}{x}\right]_2^k$$
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\left[-\frac{1}{k} - (-\frac{1}{2})\right]$$

Now for $k$, for every value of $k$ that gets closer to $\infty$ ($10^2, 10 ^3, 10^4$ and so on...), the fraction, $\frac{1}{k}$, becomes proportionally smaller and smaller ($\frac{1}{10^2}, \frac{1}{10^3}, \frac{1}{10^4}$), ie. $\frac{1}{k}$ approaches $0$. $$\lim_{k\to \infty}, \frac{1}{k} \to 0$$
$$= \left[0 - (-\frac{1}{2})\right]$$
$$\therefore \int_2^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{2}$$